# action function without action method is a client or server action?

Tags: visualforce

I have written simple button to wash away the error using action function.

1. I clicked some wrong value, it gives an error using apex page message.
2. I selected right value now.
3. I call JavaScript function to call action function which will re-render the apex page message section.

Question above is:

I simple used action function to re-render the section. which doen't have any action method in it. Do you think its a server call or client calll ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apex:actionFunction` always calls the server, even if no `action` is specified. This allows the view state to be updated and components to be rendered according to new data (typically user input, but may also be from another source).

`reRender` causes specific elements to be updated. If you do not specify a `reRender`, then the page reloads. In either case, as before, the view state is updated and elements are rendered according to updated data.

This same general behavior occurs for all elements that have an `action` and `reRender` attribute, including `apex:commandButton`, `apex:commandLink`, `apex:actionFunction`, and `apex:actionPoller`.

Answer (score 2):

`actionfunction` makes server side call when we use `action` which makes a call to controller method.

If an action is not specified, the page simply refreshes. Refer [apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)

`re-render` works on client side. Now you re-render a `pageblocktable` which is getting displayed based on list from server then definitely a server side call will be happening.